# Why does persisting entity twice avoid errors around cascading for entity with join columns

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee

Why does this unit test fail if i do not perform the setup of the entity Role in two steps (two persists).
The error being:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: During synchronization a new object was found through a relationship that was not marked cascade PERSIST: io.osram.olt.extension.jpa.Role@16daa399.`

```
    private Role addRoleWithId(String roleId){
        Role myRole = new Role();
        myRole.setRoleId(roleId);
        myRole.setRealmId("my");
        myRole.setDescription("role-description-0");
        myRole.setExternalCreator(true);
        myRole.setName("role-name-0");
        em.persist(myRole); //<--- Without this persisting the role fails with the error above.

        //Setup joins:
        myRole.setAContext(getApplications().get(0));
        myRole.setAnotherContext(getTenants().get(0));
        em.persist(myRole);
        return myRole;
    }

...
```

The Role Entity:

```
        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "ANOTHER_CONTEXT_ID")
        private AnotherContext anotherContext;

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "ACONTEXT_ID")
        private AContext aContext;

    ...
        public Role setAContext(AContext aContext) {
            this.aContext = aContext;
            if(aContext != null) {
                aContext.addRole(this);
            }
            return this;
        }

        public Role setAnotherContext(AnotherContext anotherContext) {
            this.anotherContext = anotherContext;
            if(anotherContext != null){
                anotherContext.addRole(this);
            }
            return this;
        }

    ...
```

The AContext and AnotherContext both contain similar relations towards role:

```
@OneToMany
@JoinTable(
        name="OLT_ROLES_ACONTEXT",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="ACONTEXT_ID"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="ROLE_ID")
)
private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>();
```

It seems by creating the object in two steps I can avoid using cascading.

Comment: what does `getApplications().get(0)` and `getTenants().get(0)` return ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `setAContext` and `setAnotherContext` methods, you are trying to set the `Role` object which is not yet persisted. 
So It's clear that it will not work without `em.persist(myRole);` before you set contexts since you have not specified `CaseCadeType.PERSIST`.

Answer (score 0):

The default setting for cascading is cascade NONE , which causes the relationships in the persisted entity not to be persisted by default.

the corollary is that if you try to persist an entity without cascade.PERSIST to its relationship while the relationship is not managed , you will get the above exception.

An exception of the corollary is that if the entity you are persisting is the owner of the relation and the attribute in the relation is already in the database, yo will be able to persist it.

One small thing that I noticed in your mapping : It's a double unidirectional, one with a join column and the reverse with a join table, so is this intended?